# How can I copy syntax highlighted code as RTF or HTML?

Tags: copy-paste, kill-ring, yank

I'm using Emacs to write code samples that I later want to be able to paste into a MS-Word document, preserving the syntax highlighting. I understand that in order to do this I need to copy the text in either RTF or HTML format.

Currently I'm just killing from Emacs into http://www.tohtml.com and then copying from there and pasting into Word. It strikes me that someone, somewhere has probably written some Lisp to make this process at least a couple of keystrokes shorter, but I can't seem to find any existing solution or anything in the docs that suggests this is even possible.

So I'm keen to know if there is a ready made solution I can include in my config or if anyone has any pointers about how I could write something to achieve this.

I'm fairly new to Emacs, loving it, but my e-Lisp is currently very basic.

Answer (score 6):

The `htmlize` package can do this.  Install it with `M-x package-install htmlize` and you get access to the commands `htmlize-region`

> (htmlize-region BEG END)
>
> Convert the region to HTML, preserving colors and decorations.

and `htmlize-region-for-paste`

> (htmlize-region-for-paste BEG END)
>
> Htmlize the region and return just the HTML as a string.
> This forces the ‘inline-css’ style and only returns the HTML body,
> but without the BODY tag.  This should make it useful for inserting
> the text to another HTML buffer.

Comment: Most likely, when you paste into MS-Word, you will get the RAW HTML code, when using this method.

Comment: `htmlize` can be installed from [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/htmlize).

Answer (score 6):

The package https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight2clipboard does exactly what you asked for. It use `htmlize` to create a HTML version of the text which it adds as an alternative paste text. (*Note:* This is a non-trivial operation which requires interfacing with the clipboard. This is operating system specific, currently OS X and MS-Windows are supported.)

When pasting into applications like MS-Word, the syntax highlighting is retained.

Answer (score 2):

I have this custom elisp function which I use to convert a selected region or the whole buffer to syntax fontified HTML.

```el
(defvar modi/htmlize-output-directory
  (let ((dir (concat temporary-file-directory
                     (getenv "USER") "/.htmlize/"))) ; must end with /
    (make-directory dir :parents)
    dir)
  "Output directory for files exported by `modi/htmlize-region-to-file'.")

(defvar modi/htmlize-css-file (concat user-emacs-directory
                                      "misc/css/leuven_theme.css")
  "CSS file to be embedded in the html file created using the
             `modi/htmlize-region-to-file' function.")

(defun modi/htmlize-region-to-file (option)
  "Export the selected region to an html file. If a region is not
selected, export the whole buffer.

The output file is saved to `modi/htmlize-output-directory' and its fontification
is done using `modi/htmlize-css-file'.

If OPTION is non-nil (for example, using `\\[universal-argument]' prefix), copy
the output file name to kill ring.
If OPTION is \\='(16) (using `\\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument]' prefix),
do the above and also open the html file in the default browser."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((org-html-htmlize-output-type 'css)
        (org-html-htmlize-font-prefix "org-")
        (fname (concat modi/htmlize-output-directory
                       (if (buffer-file-name)
                           (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))
                         "temp")
                       ".html"))
        start end html-string)
    (if (use-region-p)
        (progn
          (setq start (region-beginning))
          (setq end (region-end)))
      (progn
        (setq start (point-min))
        (setq end (point-max))))
    (setq html-string (org-html-htmlize-region-for-paste start end))
    (with-temp-buffer
      ;; Insert the `modi/htmlize-css-file' contents in the temp buffer
      (insert-file-contents modi/htmlize-css-file nil nil nil :replace)
      ;; Go to the beginning of the buffer and insert comments and
      ;; opening tags for `html', `head' and `style'. These are
      ;; inserted *above* the earlier inserted css code.
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (insert (concat "<!-- This file is generated using the "
                      "`modi/htmlize-region-to-file' function\n"
                      "from https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/"
                      "blob/master/setup-files/setup-org.el -->\n"))
      (insert "<html>\n<head>\n<style media=\"screen\" type=\"text/css\">\n")
      ;; Go to the end of the buffer (end of the css code) and
      ;; insert the closing tags for `style' and `head' and opening
      ;; tag for `body'.
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n")
      ;; Insert the HTML for fontified text in `html-string'.
      (insert html-string)
      ;; Close the `body' and `html' tags.
      (insert "</body>\n</html>\n")
      (write-file fname)
      (when option
        (kill-new fname)
        (when (= 16 (car option))
          (browse-url-of-file fname))))))
```

Here are few points about the `modi/htmlize-region-to-file` function:

- If the region is selected, only that region will be exported to an HTML file in `modi/htmlize-output-directory` directory.
- If no region is selected, the whole buffer will be exported.
- It requires `ox-html` (`org-mode` HTML exporter) as it uses `org-html-htmlize-region-for-paste` function which uses the `htmlize` package behind the scenes and also allows customizing how to associate CSS with the HTML code for fontification.
- It is able to fontify code based on the css file specified by `modi/htmlize-css-file` variable. To use this function right-away you can save this custom [leuven theme](https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven-theme) based [css file](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/misc/css/leuven_theme.css) somewhere and set this variable to that file path. If you use that css file, the exported code will always have the Leuven theme **regardless of your emacs theme** (which was my sole purpose for writing this function).
- I would recommend installing the [`region-bindings-mode`](https://github.com/fgallina/region-bindings-mode) package. With that installed, you simply select the region you want to export and hit <kbd>H</kbd>... Voila! Your code will be saved to an HTML file in `modi/htmlize-output-directory`.

  ```el
  (with-eval-after-load 'region-bindings-mode
      (define-key region-bindings-mode-map (kbd "H") #'modi/htmlize-region-to-file))
  ```
- If you do `C-u H`, it will export the code and copy the output file name to the kill-ring.
- If you do `C-u C-u H` instead, it will do the above and also open the HTML file it in your default browser using the `browse-url-of-file` function.

Below is what I got in my web browser when I did `C-u C-u H` on part of the above code:

### [image]

***NOTE:*** I need to save the HTML to a file. Saving the HTML annotated code just to the clipboard will not work for me because I [don't know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30673236/1219634) how to convert html code in clipboard directly to rendered html when pasting in Outlook/Word.

Answer (score 1):

[ESH](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/esh) can do this:

- Clone the ESH repository, and add `(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/the/repo")` to your `.emacs`.
- Use `M-x load-library RET esh RET` to load ESH
- Open your code file, run `M-x esh-htmlfontify-display` (this opens a browser displaying a webpage generated (locally) by ESH).
- Copy from the browser into your application.